# Algoritmo burbuja para un vector ascendente en Pseudocodigo

Tags: algoritmos, ordenamiento, pseint, pseudocódigo, sl

Estoy utilizando el algoritmo burbuja para ordenar un vector de forma ascendente en el **lenguaje SL** de **CNC**, y utilizo un software que se llama **SLE** para hacer esto. Me arroja un error que dice lo siguiente:

> Error : Se requiere `(' para poner los parámetros de la subrutina. Se encontró` i'

En este caso, no estoy utilizando surutinas para hacer este algoritmo. Pero pregunto si eso seria necesario?.

```
const 
    N = 10
var 
    i, j, aux : numerico
    array : vector[N] numerico 

inicio 
    cls 

    i = 1

    mientras (i <= N)
    {   
        array[i] = random(100)
        i = i + 1
    }

    i = 1
    imprimir ('Vector ordenado ascendente')
    desde i = 1 hasta N - 1
    {
        j = 1
        desde j = 1 hasta N - 1
        {
            si (array[j] > array[j + 1])
            {
                aux = array[j]
                array[j] = array[j + 1]
                array[j + 1] = aux
            }
        }
    }

    desde i = 1 hasta N 
    {
        imprimir (array[i])
    }
fin
```

Utilizo  **SLE** pero de puede utilizar **PSeInt** para este algoritmo.

Comment: en que linea marca el error? que es cls?

Comment: La linea 10. Entre *cls()* y el ciclo *mientras*, pero ya me di cuenta de mi error. Sucede que *cls()* le faltaban los parentesis :v... Que distraido fui